# Cancel timeout during editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to show a list of products. User can add products to this list and then it gets updated by a timeout function which loads the $scope.products each second. But these products can also be edited but because of the timeout the user only gets 1 second or less to edit the product. So when he clicks the product the edit it the timeout should been canceled until the product is edited...

**AngularJS**

```
categorieFilter.controller("catFilter", ["$scope", "$http","$timeout", "store", function($scope,$http,$timeout,store){
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.categories = [];

    $scope.removeproduct = function($prodid){
        $http.get('api/removeproduct/'+$prodid)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Product remove error: ", status, data);
        });    
    }; 
    $scope.postname = function ($prodid, $prodname){
        $timeout.cancel();
        $http.get('api/editproduct/'+$prodid+'/'+$prodname)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Product edit error: ", status, data);
        });    
    };   
    $scope.postprice = function ($prodid, $prodprice){
        $http.get('api/editproductprice/'+$prodid+'/'+$prodprice)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Productprice edit error: ", status, data);
        });    
    };       

    store.getCategories().then(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data;
    })
    store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    })    

    $scope.filterProductsByCats = function(category){
    $scope.search = category;
    };

// Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
    $scope.intervalFunctionMenu = function(){
        $timeout(function() {
        store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;

        }); 
        $scope.intervalFunctionMenu();
        }, 1000)
    };

// Kick off the interval
    $scope.intervalFunctionMenu();    


}])
```

How can this best be accomplished?

Comment: A bit unrelated, but you can use the $interval service instead of that function to replicate setInterval.

Comment: Can you use `ng-focus` on one of the fields being edited and set a `$scope` var to something like: `$scope.editing = true`? You could then have an if statement in your timeout that says `if($scope.editing){ return; }`

Comment: You need to save the identifier returned by $timeout and send that to the cancel function, otherwise you won't cancel your timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timeoutR = $timeout(...);
$timeout.cancel(timeoutR);
```

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)
Also look into [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
categorieFilter.controller("catFilter", ["$scope", "$http","$timeout", "store", function($scope,$http,$timeout,store){
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.categories = [];

    $scope.removeproduct = function($prodid){
        $http.get('api/removeproduct/'+$prodid)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Product remove error: ", status, data);
        });    
    };
var timeoutR; /* Added */
    $scope.postname = function ($prodid, $prodname){
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutR); /* I hope there is no way to get here without an timeout created */
        $http.get('api/editproduct/'+$prodid+'/'+$prodname)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Product edit error: ", status, data);
        });    
    };   
    $scope.postprice = function ($prodid, $prodprice){
        $http.get('api/editproductprice/'+$prodid+'/'+$prodprice)        
        .success(function(results){
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.error("Productprice edit error: ", status, data);
        });    
    };       

    store.getCategories().then(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data;
    })
    store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    })    

    $scope.filterProductsByCats = function(category){
    $scope.search = category;
    };

// Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
    $scope.intervalFunctionMenu = function(){
        timeoutR = $timeout(function() {/* Added */
        store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;

        }); 
        $scope.intervalFunctionMenu();
        }, 1000)
    };

// Kick off the interval
    $scope.intervalFunctionMenu();    


}])
```

Comment: Doesn't work... the timeout is still active and I get only 1 second to edit a product

Comment: @Sesamzaad can you show me where are you trying to cancel your timeout? Or update your question with new code with edits.

Comment: Great it works but now when the editing is done how can I restart the timeout function?

Comment: @Sesamzaad `$scope.intervalFunctionMenu();`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
var timer; // Define globally or where both the following two lines can access

timer = $timeout( your_code_goes_here ); // Assign timeout to timer

$timeout.cancel( timer ); // Cancel timer at the desired event
```

Comment: Doesn't work... the timeout is still active and I get only 1 second to edit a product

Comment: It should have. Can you share your code/implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can set flag (e.g. **isEdit=true**), when user starts to edit product, and check this flag in your **intervalFunctionMenu** function.